# Manipulated Group Child Data In ListView in dart/flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to show, first of all, the Group name then below all child products of the particular group. but I can not populate the data.

model class:

```
class PromotionOfferModel {
  String offerID;
  String offerTitle;
  String offerDescription;
  String offerType;
  String offerBaseProductBrandID;
  String offerBaseProductBrandTitle;
  String offerBaseProductID;
  String offerBaseProductTitle;
  double offerBaseProductQtyCtn;
  double offerBaseProductQtyPcs;
  String offerProductID;
  String offerProductTitle;
  double offerProductQtyCtn;
  double offerProductQtyPcs;
  double offerProductQtyCtnMin;
  double offerProductQtyCtnMax;
  double offerProductQtyPcsMin;
  double offerProductQtyPcsMax;
  double discountOnProduct;
  String entryParameter;

  PromotionOfferModel(
      {this.offerID,
        this.offerTitle,
        this.offerDescription,
        this.offerType,
        this.offerBaseProductBrandID,
        this.offerBaseProductBrandTitle,
        this.offerBaseProductID,
        this.offerBaseProductTitle,
        this.offerBaseProductQtyCtn,
        this.offerBaseProductQtyPcs,
        this.offerProductID,
        this.offerProductTitle,
        this.offerProductQtyCtn,
        this.offerProductQtyPcs,
        this.offerProductQtyCtnMin,
        this.offerProductQtyCtnMax,
        this.offerProductQtyPcsMin,
        this.offerProductQtyPcsMax,
        this.discountOnProduct,
        this.entryParameter});

  PromotionOfferModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    offerID = json['offerID'];
    offerTitle = json['offerTitle'];
    offerDescription = json['offerDescription'];
    offerType = json['offerType'];
    offerBaseProductBrandID = json['offerBaseProductBrandID'];
    offerBaseProductBrandTitle = json['offerBaseProductBrandTitle'];
    offerBaseProductID = json['offerBaseProductID'];
    offerBaseProductTitle = json['offerBaseProductTitle'];
    offerBaseProductQtyCtn = json['offerBaseProductQtyCtn'];
    offerBaseProductQtyPcs = json['offerBaseProductQtyPcs'];
    offerProductID = json['offerProductID'];
    offerProductTitle = json['offerProductTitle'];
    offerProductQtyCtn = json['offerProductQtyCtn'];
    offerProductQtyPcs = json['offerProductQtyPcs'];
    offerProductQtyCtnMin = json['offerProductQtyCtnMin'];
    offerProductQtyCtnMax = json['offerProductQtyCtnMax'];
    offerProductQtyPcsMin = json['offerProductQtyPcsMin'];
    offerProductQtyPcsMax = json['offerProductQtyPcsMax'];
    discountOnProduct = json['discountOnProduct'];
    entryParameter = json['entryParameter'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['offerID'] = this.offerID;
    data['offerTitle'] = this.offerTitle;
    data['offerDescription'] = this.offerDescription;
    data['offerType'] = this.offerType;
    data['offerBaseProductBrandID'] = this.offerBaseProductBrandID;
    data['offerBaseProductBrandTitle'] = this.offerBaseProductBrandTitle;
    data['offerBaseProductID'] = this.offerBaseProductID;
    data['offerBaseProductTitle'] = this.offerBaseProductTitle;
    data['offerBaseProductQtyCtn'] = this.offerBaseProductQtyCtn;
    data['offerBaseProductQtyPcs'] = this.offerBaseProductQtyPcs;
    data['offerProductID'] = this.offerProductID;
    data['offerProductTitle'] = this.offerProductTitle;
    data['offerProductQtyCtn'] = this.offerProductQtyCtn;
    data['offerProductQtyPcs'] = this.offerProductQtyPcs;
    data['offerProductQtyCtnMin'] = this.offerProductQtyCtnMin;
    data['offerProductQtyCtnMax'] = this.offerProductQtyCtnMax;
    data['offerProductQtyPcsMin'] = this.offerProductQtyPcsMin;
    data['offerProductQtyPcsMax'] = this.offerProductQtyPcsMax;
    data['discountOnProduct'] = this.discountOnProduct;
    data['entryParameter'] = this.entryParameter;
    return data;
  }
}
```

still, now, show data 1) group name 2) product name of the particular group.
I want to display the result

1. Group Name
   a) product name
   b) product name
   c) product name
   d) product name
   my source code given is below:

   ```
      ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _mOfferList == null
              ? 0
              : _mOfferList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return Card(
              // margin:
              //     EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                    elevation: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          _mOfferList[
                          index].offerBaseProductBrandTitle,
                          textAlign:
                          TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13.0),

                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            // Emp Info
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                // color: Color(0xFF90EE90),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child:
                                          _mOfferList[index].offerTitle ==
                                              null
                                              ? Text("  ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13.0))
                                              : Text(
                                            "" +
                                                _mOfferList[
                                                index].offerTitle,
                                            textAlign:
                                            TextAlign.left,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13.0),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // end of Emp Info
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ));
              }),
   ```

Stil now my result:

```
Group Name : AAA
 a) abc
Group Name : AAA
 b) xxx
Group Name : AAA
 c) yyy
Group Name : AAA
 d) zzz
Group Name : BBB
 a) gtt
Group Name : BBB
 b) gbt
Group Name : BBB
 c) kosadfa
Group Name : BBB
 d) sdfsadf
```

But my wanted result: like below

```
Group Name : AAA
        a) abc
        b) xxx
        c) yyy
        d) zzz
Group Name : BBB
        a) gtt
        b) gbt
        c) kosadfa
        d) sdfsadf
```

Comment: Can you include the group data, `_mOfferList`? How this thing is organized, and what is the logic behind grouping?

Comment: group and child data have within one list

Comment: how do you define a list that is combination of item+groupName

Comment: I have add model class, you will understand now. hope